# Different CSS mask-position values per mask-image in a composite mask

Tags: css

I have two mask images to use for composite mask, being set as the mask-image property. I'd like to specify a different mask-position value for each image, since the images are different sizes and not positioned to the same scale.

```
.my-class {
  mask-image: url(/masks/foo.png), url(/masks/bar.png);
  mask-position: ?; /* Set 0 for foo.png, but 15px -50px for bar.png */
  mask-size: 100%;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

foo.png and bar.png should have different mask-position values. I need an offset on bar.png before I can add it to foo.png.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, per the current spec, which is in initial definition (and is experimental, so it may change). From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-position:

```
mask-position: 0 0, 15px -50px;
```

This follows the pattern for positioning multiple background images.